# Uploading pdf files to Mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, file, uploading

I am unable to upload the pdf documents that are created using Photoshop and PDFTK. Other pdf documents are getting uploaded without any problem.

I am getting the following warning:

> `fread()`: supplied argument is not a
>   valid stream resource in
>
> Warning: `fclose()`: supplied argument
>   is not a valid stream resource

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't suggest uploading the PDFs to MySQL - you would have to save it as a BLOB, and then read the BLOB. This will bloat your database quickly and cause speed issues.

Instead, upload the PDF to the file system, and save the PATH to the PDF in MySQL. Then you can read that path from MySQL.

However, if you absolutely need to save the file as a BLOB - here is a good tutorial for doing so:
http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: @Avisra, one benefit of saving in the database is that you cannot lose those files due to renaming etc, so saving in the database can be a good idea, opinions differ widely on this issue. Performance wise you are right though.

Comment: Sorry, I am uploading them by saving as BLOB only. the problem here is I am getting warnings when I upload the pdf created from Photoshop and PDFTK.

Comment: That is a very good point. I've seen content management systems (like Sitefinity) use the same method. It save's documents as BLOBs and then reads them in. What would be really cool is some kind of caching system supporting it. If the file contents or path hasn't changed - read from a cache file on the server. Otherwise, read in the BLOB from MySQL and re-cache it.

Comment: @Sanch, can you post your current PHP code for uploading to MySQL and the code for pulling in the BLOB? (where you are using fread).

Comment: $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
if($fileName !="")
{
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
}
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}
//$fileName=str_replace(" ","_",$fileName);

$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content,topic,country,dc) VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content','$topic','$country','$dc')";

Comment: if($type=="application/pdf")
{
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
//header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $content;
}
else
{
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $content;
//header("Location: $name");
  //exit;
mysql_close();

}

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted in my answer above. Instead of using fread($fp, filesize($tmpName), try using file_get_contents($tmpName)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I followed the same as listed in the page. and also used file_get_contents($tmpName).but the same error is coming.for all other pdf docs,its working fine.its only the problem with Photoshop,PDFTK pdf docs.

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string, and don't use addslashes. Also, generate a unique name using uniqid or microtime, and save the PDF with that name to wherever you save the file. And then in your database, save the new filename alongside the original filename. This way you won't get any conflicts when someone uploads a file with the same exact name as a previously uploaded file.